# connecting to websocket locally with wamp

Tags: php, websocket, wamp

I am trying to do a tutorial on websockets, however it seems I can't even connect to the websocket.

I am using wamp 2.5 and I have php_sockets extension **enabled**.

In the video, the guy's url for the homepage is: `youtube:app:8000`, and mine is `l/chat` (I turned localhost into l a while ago), and it opens up normally.

Then, he sets up the server like so:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:2000");
```

And since it's just the first step with no more code, when he goes to the homepage (youtube:app:8000) he gets this message in chrome:

```
Error during websocket handshake
```

Whereas I get:

```
Error in connection establishment
```

When setting my new websocket, I tried all 3 following options, but the error is always the same (I never get to the handshake).

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://l:2000");
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2000");
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:2000");
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Do you have anything set up to listen on port 2000?

Comment: No, I just followed the tutorial to the letter.

Comment: I also did the tutorial from ratchet website, all was well until the end when I tried to make a new websocket with js, and I got the same error as when doing this tutorial.

Comment: Try dropping the port number.  Should just be `var socket = new WebSocket('ws://l');`. That'll default to port 80, which since Apache is running through WAMP, will give you a different message.

Comment: The message actually changed to 'error during handshake', but the last part of the error is different. For him it is: 'failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED' and for me it is: 'failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200' . Any idea about this?

Comment: It's sounding like Chrome updated their error messages since the tutorial was recorded.  The "net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED" message is the same, semantically, as "Error in connection establishment"...  They both mean that the connection was dropped as soon as it was created, as is expected when there is nothing listening for a connection on a given port.  -- **Bottom line**: Should be safe to continue to tutorial.

Comment: Thank you so much, hopefully it will work out. Feel free to post this as the answer and I will be happy to accept.